# Display Message When copy any word in TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to Display any Message in `Toast` when I select and copy any word from `TextView` in my android app.

Suppose if I have "Display Toast" as a String in my `TextView` and if I select "Display" then It should be there in `Toast`.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: In the title you say you want to show message when word is *copied* to clipboard. In your question you say you want to show the message when you *select* the word. Which one is the one you want?

Comment: Oh Thank you for your interesting. please if you have a time can you help me with tow options.

Comment: I want features like translator if I select and copy a word in my App ,I want show a Toast explaining the mean of word in another language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) Unfortunately I'm not an Android developer and can't really help you here. I only reviewed your question and thought it needed some clarification (which @Abhishek provided). I hope you get your answer. Here's also a link to help you ask quality questions in the future [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).